# Qt C++ restart itself

Tags: c++, qt, restart

The app is memory leaking, so as a temporary solution I would check how much memory it takes, kill the process and restart the app.

Is there any easy way to do that?

Thank you

Comment: Why do you need to do this rather than fixing the leak by introspecting the valgrind or similar output? Anyway, couldn't you write a wrapper for your application which calls the "free" util or use "/proc/meminfo", closes your application, and then restarts it? It is hard to do properly for cross-platform, but it is certainly possible.

Answer (score 1):

You should fix the memory leak. Any way if you want to restart your application, you can use `QProcess::startDetached` to run an instance of your application in a new process and detach from it. After that you should exit the application.

This will restart your application :

```
QProcess process;
process.startDetached("myApp",QStringList());

qApp->quit();
```

Here `myApp` is the name of the executable file of the application. On Windows it can be `myApp.exe`.

Answer (score 0):

You could override new and delete to keep allocation statistics for the program and then when a threshold is reached based on available mem, abort().  Then in an external script you could restart.

Also see the excellent gimli monitor, here: https://bitbucket.org/wez/gimli/wiki/Monitor

Comment: do you happen to have an example illustrating that?

Comment: Not handy, no.  I think the valgrind approach to find the leak suggested by Laszlo Papp above is a good one here.

Answer (score 0):

To restart application by itself, try:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QProcess>

...

// restart:
qApp->quit();
QProcess::startDetached(qApp->arguments()[0], qApp->arguments());
```